# Xamarin Android: Change EditText's bottom border color if it contains a value

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext

Please find below image for your reference:
[image]

I want to set a colored underline / bottom border for the **EditText** if **`EditText`** has any value in it (at the time of value change itself).

I have tried to set theme programmatically for this but it was not working.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(editText.Text))
  editText.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.EditTextStyle);
```

Comment: Are all those different Edittext or the same?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an XML file into your drawable folder suppose EdittextStyle.xml

   2.Add the following code into the xml file :

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:bottom="1dp"
    android:top="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp" 
    android:left="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
    <stroke
       android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@color/colorRedText" />
    </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
   ```

   3.As per your requirement on the TextChanged event of your EditText add this code:

   ```
     Editext.TextChanged+= delegate
   {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(editText.Text))
     editText.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.drawable.EdittextStyle);
   };
   ```

Hope it helps!
Goodluck!

Comment: mark it as right please so those other people who have the same query might find this easily @prajapatisanket